# Cannot connect to gitlab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I want to pull the newest update on my gitlab, I hit git pull origin master, it returns connection reset by  port 22, i keep trying to do

eval `ssh-agent` then ssh-add ~/.ssh/
and hit `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` but still get
Connection reset by 172.65.251.78 port 22

Answer (score 0):

If even `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` does not work (does not return a Welcome message), then maybe your network environment does not allow SSH.

Generally, ingress SSH is forbidden in a corporate setting, but SSH URL for cloning should still work!

Also, ssh-agent is only needed if your private key is passphrase-protected (and therefore encrypted). Try first with a passphrase-less key, to see if it makes any difference.

Check also your permissions in your `~/.ssh` folder (as [seen here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467555/7490)), in case they are too opened.
Check if adding [`-o TCPKeepAlive=true` could help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334440/7490).

Comment: I was facing the same problem too, but after changing to another ISP for connection, it worked.

Comment: @wuku Good. That solution would not be available in a working environment, where you have only the company network to connect to though.